# Sample databases for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, northwind, adventureworks

To practice and learn more about databases, I’m searching besides the well-known databases like AdventureWorks and Northwind for more exemplary databases. Are there any or any which are possible to migrate from other databases?

Comment: +1. While the AdventureWorks (and Northwind, and Pubs) databases have some merits due to visibility, there are three issues: (1) I've lost track of all the different versions; (2) I know there are some versions that don't install well either due to requirements or features like FILESTREAM; and (3) they're not exactly the best schema/index models to begin with. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [SQL Server 2005 Express Starter Data Models](https://www.facultyresourcecenter.com/curriculum/TH/pfv.aspx?ID=6687&c1=th-th&c2=TH&Login=) provides 10 sample database models. While referring to 2005 in the title, they can also be used in 2008.

From Codeplex:

- [Microsoft SQL Server Community Projects & Samples](http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/) all kinds of samples, not only data models
- [KiGG](http://kigg.codeplex.com/) [Create.sql](http://kigg.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3a9b436eace5#Source/Database/Create.sql)
- [Umbraco](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/) [.sql](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c036440073f6#Source/Libraries/Umbraco.Framework.Persistence.NHibernate/Sql/CreateSchemaAndDefaultData_SqlServer.sql)

or [search for "SQL" on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=sql&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=%7C)